# How to display time remaining, filename, etc., on vlc's OSD (On Screen Display)?

Tags: linux, debian, vlc-media-player, osd, marquee

I have tried:

Preferences > All > Video > Subtitles/OSD:

Enabled 'Marquee Display'

Then,

Preferences > All > Video > Subtitles/OSD > Marquee > Text:

%H:%M, $t, $P

This is what I get:

[Image where $ is displayed as $. Only % values are replaced correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg4Oz.jpg)

***Why are the $ values not being expanded?***

I got the $ values from:

https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Format_String/

Googling for this problem gave me info like, "Meta-data expansion in marquee is not implemented. As far as I am aware, it was never implemented in LibVLC at all."

**Is there some way to fix this? Or are there other ways to display more info in the vlc OSD?**

Answer (score 3):

I tried hard to get this to work too, to no avail. Apparently this feature isn't supported.

But I found a workaround in this YouTube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BuZ8Wj3Qjdk

The workaround is to use a VLC extension called "Time v3.2". You can download it from here:
https://addons.videolan.org/p/1154032/

The extension is a zip file. When unzipped, there are two folders, "extensions" and "intf", with one file in each. Those files need to be saved in the VLC's folder. The video explains how to install the extension on Windows. I use a Mac myself, so file locations are different. On macOS, the paths where to put the extension files are:

time_intf.lua: /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/intf

time_ext.lua: /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/extensions

After copying the files to those folders, restart VLC. On macOS, open the extension from the menu VLC media player > Extensions > Time v3.2 intf.

In the dialog box that opens, enable the setting "Enable interface:" and click "SAVE!". Restart VLC.

Play some video in VLC. Reopen the extension from the menu. You can now select different meta patterns from the dropdown list, then click the ">>> USE PATTERN" button, which copies the pattern to the free-form text field. Finally, click the "START!" button, and your chosen pattern is displayed on the screen.

The string you want to enter in the field is: [T], [n], [P]%

Hope this helps anyone trying to solve this same problem.

Comment: Is it possible to disable the time display that "pops up" in the top-right corner whenever you skip backward/forward? It's redundant when Time v.32 is doing its thing. (I'm using Windows, but I would think the mechanism would be the same.)